# Protractor conf.js gives 'no specs found' only when run through batch script's variable

Tags: shell, protractor, config

I am reading a string (name of a file stored in another file) to a variable in bash script.
My original command to run is

```
protractor conf.js --specs 'LeadershipBoard.js'
```

which works good if written directly in script file. But the below does not work.

```
protractor conf.js --specs $value
```

And returns "No specs found. Finished in 0 seconds". Here is my RunConf.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<string.txt)
echo $value           // 'LeadershipBoard.js'

commandForConf="protractor conf.js --specs $value"
echo $commandForConf  // protractor conf.js --specs 'LeadershipBoards.js'

eval "$commandForConf"   // No specs found
eval "protractor conf.js --specs  'LeadershipBoard.js'"   // 6 specs found, 0 failures
```

I want eval "$commandForConf" to work. Here is the log on console

```
$ sh RunConf.sh  
'LeadershipBoard.js'  
protractor conf.js --specs ﻿'LeadershipBoard.js'  
[15:49:35] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub   
[15:49:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver  
Started  

No specs found Finished in 0 seconds  

[15:49:46] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running  
[15:49:46] I/launcher - internet explorer11 #01 passed  
[15:49:54] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub  
[15:49:54] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver Started  


6 specs, 0 failures Finished in 58.478 seconds  
[15:51:00] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running  
[15:51:00] I/launcher - internet explorer11 #01 passed
```

Comment: its definitely file permission issue. check for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error was from the file "string.txt" to which I was saving data from a HTML save as file js function. It was having a weird character which is not shown on shell's echo or notepad text.

I tried repeating the steps in a batch file when I saw that character. I stripped the character using js regex. That solved the issue.